# Где расположена официальная документация HTML?

Tags: html, веб-программирование, документация

Где взять *официальную*, *легальную* документацию об HTML? Я нашел много сайтов, но они, как мне кажется, сторонние и не от самого разработчика

Answer (score 4):

Смотрящие за стандартами - ребята из W3C. Конкретно про html5 они пишут тут https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/
Всё остальное ересь и от лукавого :)

upd.: вот ещё посвежее аж про 5.2! https://w3c.github.io/html/ за их же авторством.

upd.: кстати, ссылки на оф.документацию можно было найти тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/html/info

Comment: Есть ещё https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/

Answer (score 0):

Все на https://www.w3.org/. HTML и все прочее (XML,CSS,YAML,XHTML,MathML,SVG).

А так же хотел бы посоветовать сайт хороший сайт по обучению использования и документации: https://www.w3schools.com/.

Comment: Насчет второго: "Его название происходит от World Wide Web, но _не связано_ с W3C (World Wide Web Consortium). Он управляется компанией Refsnes Data в Норвегии" - Wikipedia.org.

Comment: @Anon_ch Да, точно. Сейчас поменяю. Но сайт хороший.

Comment: Для полноты картины: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @D-side Я не знаю, что ответить! Ой все 